# Dlang string to char * conversion

Tags: c, d

I've got this code reading from a bin file.
the data is held in an array of structs and null terminated
My goal is to read data, written in c-code with 
`write (filehandle, (char *)arrayOfCELLs, sizeof(arrayOfCELLs);` 
to a file, into the same structure arrayOfCELLs using D.

My problem is that in c I read the file into a struct arr[] via a cast to (char *)

```
read(filehandle, (char *)arrayOfStructs, sizeof(arrayOfStructs)
```

In D I found out through [rcorre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1435461/rcorre) that led me to [rawRead](https://dlang.org/phobos/std_stdio.html#.File.rawRead)

```
auto buffer = FileHandle.rawRead(arrayOfStructs)
```

where the buffer gets the data to the sizeof arrayOfStructs.

However, here comes my problem, the buffer seems to get the rawdata including nulltermination but all positioned in [0] of the receiving Array, also, I don't understand/know what the datatype it is(CELL[] or string[] or .....

```
struct CELL{ char [20] name, int sect, int type ...};
struct CELL [50] arrayOfCELLs;
auto buffer = ..rawRead(arrayOfCELLs)
```

received data in the buffer is (part of it) this

```
[CELL("TEST\0feed\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 1, 1,
```

The first is the name, "TEST" followed by null-termination, then sect = 1, ptyp = 1 . Now the second CELL holds this

```
CELL("\x01\0\0\0\x02\0\0\0N\0\0\0\x04\0\0\0\x02\0\0\0", 65656, 655375,
```

And that is all wrong, Should be "test" and 2,1, 
If I do a cat in the terminal I get

```
anders$ cat cellspec
TESTfeedOx
atestTailingNx
aOF2 cycl primO?
```

Question, any ideas why this is and what can I do to get it right?

Comment: can you post somewhere your cellspec, or your C and D code

Comment: Hope this download link works, its for cellspec https://1drv.ms/u/s!AmN2cOqroYulgpAx8xZrCQEuj6pR9A

Comment: And here is the d code https://1drv.ms/u/s!AmN2cOqroYulgpAynYqWHK_zAJ011g

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found out what the problem is with the conversions.
The long and unsigned long in C is not the same size in Dlang long and ulong

Solution/conclusion is when coding in D-lang and using C typed data in files, in order to get the reading correct one needs to beware that D-lang type size might not be equal to C size. 
In my case the code changed to use c_long and c_ulong to get the reading correct. After that all was well reading data.
Happy days

Answer (score 1):

What you probably need are calls to toStringz() and fromStringz(). (Documentation page: http://dlang.org/phobos/std_string.html)

Example (from the abovementioned page):

```
import core.stdc.string : strlen;
import std.conv : to;

auto p = toStringz("foo");
assert(strlen(p) == 3);
const(char)[] foo = "abbzxyzzy";
p = toStringz(foo[3..5]);
assert(strlen(p) == 2);

assert(fromStringz(null) == null);
assert(fromStringz("foo") == "foo");
```

Also, rawRead() returns the same type as the type of the buffer. So, since you have

```
auto buffer = f.rawRead(cellTab);
```

, then the `buffer` is already an array of CELL's... You should be able to use it with, say `buffer[0].name` to grab the name of the first cell...

Keep in mind that .name is actually char[20]. You really want to convert it to a string if you want to do some operations with it.

Comment: Hmmm, I don't get your example.

Comment: Your title says "Dlang string to char* conversion" - toStringz() is the answer. Simple as that.

Comment: Ahh OK, sorry was in the clouds with my problem.... Have tried however and it spits out char [] ignoring the \0 termination somewhere. When I make the rawRead it seems to fetch data into a string somehow, Though I have to reflect on that the data itself is wrong aswell. I'll consider marking your answer as the answer but that isn't what I'm looking for

Comment: Then update the question and made it more concise, and the D community will do our best to help you! :)